# Gurobi linear constraint

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, gurobi

What is the simplest way to add this constraint to gurobi in Python.

D is a given matrix with positive entries (constant).
b is a vector of my variables.
T and K are given constants.

[image: equation constraint]

Comment: In fact, In order to remove the "max" I need only sum over those boxes where \sum_j D_{ij}b_j > T . But then I'm not sure how to input this in gurobi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gurobi has added support for Max, Min, Abs, And, and Or in version 7.0. See the Gurobi doc for model.addGenConstrMax at http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/refman/py_model_addgenconstrmax.html.

So a more straightforward solution can now be coded:

```
Dmatrix = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]                                          
m = grb.Model("test_max_constraint")

M = 3
N = 2

T = 20.0 #Const
K = 15 #Const

b = {}
for j in range(N):
    b[j] = m.addVar(name='b_'+str(j))

maxterm = {}
sumterm = {}
for i in range(M):
    maxterm[i] = m.addVar(name='maxvar_'+str(i))
    sumterm[i] = m.addVar(name='sumvar_'+str(i))

m.update() #integrate the b variables

#By looping twice, explicity create the individual terms
for i in range(M):
    sum_terms = 0
    for j in range(N):
        sum_terms += Dmatrix[i][j]*b[j]
    m.addConstr(sumterm[i] == sum_terms, 'sumterm' + str(i))
    m.addGenConstrMax(maxterm[i], [sumterm[i]], T, 'maxTsum' + str(i))

m.addConstr(grb.quicksum([maxterm[i] for i in range(M)]) >= K,  "Maxterms_GT_K_Constraint")

m.update()
m.write('gurmax.lp')
```

This produces the model:

```
\ Model test_max_constraint
\ LP format - for model browsing. Use MPS format to capture full model detail.
Minimize

Subject To
 sumterm0: - b_0 - 2 b_1 + sumvar_0 = 0
 sumterm1: - 3 b_0 - 4 b_1 + sumvar_1 = 0
 sumterm2: - 5 b_0 - 6 b_1 + sumvar_2 = 0
Maxterms_GT_K_Constraint: maxvar_0 + maxvar_1 + maxvar_2 >= 15
Bounds
General Constraints
 maxTsum0: maxvar_0 = MAX ( sumvar_0 , 20 )
 maxTsum1: maxvar_1 = MAX ( sumvar_1 , 20 )
 maxTsum2: maxvar_2 = MAX ( sumvar_2 , 20 )
End
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up to my attention. And welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it. Note that since the max() term is a bit tricky, I don't use list comprehensions, relying instead on looping over the indices. (I don't have Gurobi handy to test the following.)

```
from gurobipy import *

Dmatrix = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
mod = Model("test_max_constraint")

M = 3
N = 2

T = 20 #Const
K = 15 #Const

for j in range(N):
    b[j] = model.addVar(name='b_'+str(j))

mod.update() #integrate the b variables

#By looping twice, explicity create the individual terms
maxterms = []
for i in range(M):
    current_term = 0
    for j in range(N):
        current_term += Dmatrix[i][j]*b[j]
    current_term = max(current_term-T,0)

    maxterms.append(current_term)
#A list called 'maxterms' is now ready. Add a constraint summing over these terms.

mod.addConstr( quicksum(maxterms) > K,  "Maxterms_GT_K_Constraint")
```

Hope this helps you move forward.

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting to see in your solution that gurobi can handle the "max" function within a constraint. I was trying to decompose it by using dummy variables.

Comment: @WilmerE.Henao Note that it is Python that is doing all the work. The max() section of the code is pure Python. Only when we come to *addConstr* do we invoke Gurobi functionality.

Comment: I went ahead and plugged it on the machine. This line gives me an error though 
current_term = max(Rlim - current_term, 0.0).

TypeError: unorderable types: float() > LinExpr()

Comment: You are getting a Python error, because you are comparing two different types. Try type(Rlim) to see what type it is. In order to be able to compare with 0.0 you might have to do *float()* first, then compare.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is fatally flawed. This line:<br/>

    current_term = max(current_term-T,0)<br/>

does not make sense to take a max of a gurobi variable or LinExpr. To correct this, we can add additional gurobi variables and constraints so that the model will use the max of the given expression. <br/>

However, with Gurobi 7.0, there is now support for a Max constraint. See my solution here.